# I'm building an application in Kivy but I'm having difficulty passing values ​from one screen to another

Tags: python, kivy

I have a login screen built, but when the user enters their username and clicks enter, I need to generate a new screen and use the username entered on the previous screen. I'm having difficulty passing information between the screen construction classes.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
import mysql.connector

Window.size = (400, 700)

KV = '''
Screen:

    MDScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: container
            
            
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "JOBS"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: x]]
        
        TelaLogin:



<GeneralBody>
        
    MDBottomNavigation:
        #panel_color: "#eeeaea"
        selected_color_background: "orange"
        text_color_active: "lightgrey"
        

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'global'
            text: 'Global'
            icon: 'earth'
            
                
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Pesquisa Global'
                halign: 'center'
                

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'my space'
            text: 'My Space'
            icon: 'account'

            MDLabel:
                text: root.user_name
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}
                halign: 'center'
            
            
            
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "user"
                icon_size: "170sp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
            
            MDLabel:
                id: user_job
                text: root.user_job
                font_size: 22
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .45}
                halign: 'center'
                bold: True
                
            
            MDLabel:
                id: competencia_space
                text: "Especializações e Competências"
                font_size: 15
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .35}
                halign: 'center'
                size_hint: (.9, None)
                
                
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'profile edit'
            text: 'Edit'
            icon: 'book-edit'

            MDLabel:
                text: root.user_name
                font_size: 22
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .92}
                halign: 'center'
                
            
            Spinner:
                id: spinner_id
                text: 'Profissão'
                values: root.data_jobs
                size_hint: (.9, None)
                size: (100, 44)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}
                
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)
            
            MDLabel:
                text: "Especializações e Competências"
                font_size: 15
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .66}
                halign: 'center'
                bold: True
            
            MDTextField:
                id: competencias_id
                size_hint: (.9, .6)
                hint_text: "Especializações e Competências"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .33}
                mode: "rectangle"
                
                on_text: root.competencias_input(competencias_id.text)
            
            
                    

            
<TelaLogin>:

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "alpha-j"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
        icon_size: '300sp'
        
    MDTextField:
        id: username_id
        size_hint_x: .9
        hint_text: "username"
        mode: "rectangle"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
        
    
    MDTextField:
        id: senha
        size_hint_x: .9
        hint_text: "Senha"
        mode: "rectangle"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
    
    
    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint_x: .9
        text: "Entrar"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}
        on_release: root.login(root.username)
    
    MDLabel:
        text: "By Thiago Developer"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
    
'''

class GeneralBody(FloatLayout):
    username = # I need the username value from login screen at this point.


    def spinner_clicked(self, value):
        self.user_job = value
        print(value)
        self.ids.user_job.text = value

    def competencias_input(self, value):
        self.competencias = value
        print(value)
        self.ids.competencia_space.text = value
    ...


class TelaLogin(FloatLayout):
    username = "tmb.dev"

    def login(self, username):

        self.username = self.ids.username_id.text
        print(self.username)

        print("Realizando Login"
              )
        acess = True

        print("Logado")

        if acess == True:
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.add_widget(GeneralBody())


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        #self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        #self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)




MyApp().run()
```

I've actually already spent a few days trying and reading the documentation, I'm not getting positive results.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this solves your issue.

class GeneralBody(FloatLayout):
username = ""

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    print(self.username)
```

class TelaLogin(FloatLayout):
username = "tmb.dev"

```
def login(self, username):

     GeneralBody.username = self.ids.username_id.text
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).